# Sharepoint 2010 Workflow from Visio 2010 - Multiple Approval Process 2nd and 3rd blank?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, workflow

We have designed a custom workflow using Visio 2010. The workflow has been imported into a Sharepoint 2010 Server team site and is attached to a list. The workflow has three "start approval process" which uses the OOTB approval process . When I go to edit the workflow in Sharepoint 2010 Designer, I go through each step customizing it. Everything is working right up until I get to the second "start approval process" (the first "start approval process" allows me to see the entire structure and customize it to my liking). I click on the second one, it opens in another window with more properties, I select "Change the behavior of the overall task process" and there is no logic at all on this approval process, it is completely blank and only has an opening step (start typing or use the insert group in the ribbon).

When I take this same Visio 2010 and import it into a completely different Sharepoint 2010 Server, import it and try the same process, it works fine...I can modify all the approval process points.

I should state the difference between the two is that the one in which everything works, I'm importing and changing as a farm admin (test system). The other Sharepoint server in which it is not working, I definitely do not have full admin.

I'm willing to bet it is a permission issue, if it is, what permission should I grant and why is it working for one but not all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangest thing, as soon as I completely closed Sharepoint Designer and re-opened it again, this issue did not occur!

Lesson learned, don't leave apps open on your desktop so long, Reggie!